# Play button on iOS 8+ not centering

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

I've been looking for a solution for this problem, but until now I've not been able to find any.

I need to give a video an absolute position, and its size will change according to this positioning (by giving top, right, bottom and left values). When I do this, the play button on iPhones running iOS 8+ stops being centered.

Here's a print of what is happening:

[Print screen from iPhone 5c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5TXa.png)

I've been able to reproduce this error on a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hwgnzwzf/2/ - It seems to start occurring when I set a "left" property.

```
<div class="video-holder">
    <div class="video">
        <div class="video-wrapper video-wide">
            <video controls poster="http://placehold.it/200x200">
                <source src="" type="video/mp4"/>
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


.video{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:40%;
    right:20%;
    bottom:0;
}
```

/edit: After Doml's input I tried setting only the 'right' value and a 'max-width', but the final result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

the Problem is, that iOS needs both properties, either top / left | bottom /right and you simply put it to 40%
A better solution to "center" an absolute container is to put it to the center of the screen and the put it half way back it's width:

```
left:50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

i don't own an iphone so please tell me if this works out for you

edit://  oh and if you want to "resize" it simply add a max-width to it and remove the "right" property

Comment: Hi, Doml. I need to give all the coordinates to the '.video' div, so I can position that div inside the 'notebook screen', as I tried to show on the print above. As everything is responsive, I needed to set percentages, so it always fit exactly inside.

And, anyway, even by using your suggestion, the play button was still misplaced. :-/ Thanks a lot, either way! :)

Comment: Here's the JSFiddle update using your proposed solution: https://jsfiddle.net/hwgnzwzf/4/ - It stills makes the play button overlay to be positioned to the right side when looking on the iPhone browser [http://i.imgur.com/750omCf.png] (Print screen).

Comment: really difficult question - seems to be a usual problem on IOS there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405684/html5-video-play-symbol-not-centered-in-mobile-safari

Answer (score 0):

It's an iOS issue, my solution would be to remove video controls attribute so we remove the iOS style, then we add it again with css.

With js we can add controls again on a click and play video with html5 api.

Then, the solution might be something like https://jsfiddle.net/99eanxjr/1/

```
$('video').on('click', function(e){
    var video = this;
    $(video).attr('controls', true).parent().addClass('started');
    video.play();
});
```

Obviously, you might keep in mind that this is a kind of hacky solution, and should be conditional to your needs, like execute this only with iOS and drop this hack after a real fix released. CSS prefixer needed too. =P

I've just written, need test! =)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For me at least (testing on iphone6 plus) the problem is caused by

```
div[pseudo="-webkit-media-controls"] {
  min-width: 260px;
}
```

which is in the user agent stylesheet for the #document-fragment created by ios. I am testing in browserstack and when I inspect the element I can see this is the cause.

I have searched a bit but can't find a way to target #document-fragments with css or javascript. So... I'm stuck but I feel this is the right direction.